# How to set router meta on vue from api like role array dynamically

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I have a dynamic role system which admin can add or delete the role. I search how to add role in vue router in meta as array base on this role access level
I am trying to add it via store it not working. How can get roles from API and set it in vue router? maybe I doing the wrong way because I am new to vuejs can any help me out thanks.

I am tried to add vuex store to add router meta but I have roles in store not setting it on the router meta

````
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home,
      children: [
        {
          path: '/users',
          meta: { label: 'Users', role: store.getters.roles },
          component: Users
        }]```


``` path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home,
      children: [
        {
          path: '/users',
          meta: { label: 'Users', role: ['admin','staf'] },
          component: Users
        }, ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the (non-reactive) routes object is created before the relevant information in the vuex store is present (as most likely your API request isn't yet fulfilled), `store.getters.roles` is still empty or null. A solution would be to instead put a function in the meta object that can be called whenever the access-system does its role-checking: `meta: { roles: () => store.getters.roles }`.
Simply check against `route.meta.roles()` upon navigation requests.

---

#### Old answer (misinterpreted question)

I am not exactly sure what you're trying to do with the vuex store, but I guess you're trying to keep 'Home' accessible for all roles. What I'd suggest doing is simply removing the `role` field from these routes (I'd also rename it to `roles`, as it can be multiple, but that's up to you). Then, to enforce the access-system use something along the lines of:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const user = yourAuthentication.user
  const lacksRole = to.matched.some(route => {
    return route.meta.roles && !route.meta.roles.includes(user.role)
  })

  if (lacksRole) {
    return next(false)  // Aborts the navigation request
  }

  // Route either doesn't require any role or user has one of the 
  // roles specified in the route meta object, continue navigation
  next()
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer but may I have to add some detail to make it understandable I am not trying match role but instead try to set the  roles in meta from the store to make sure this added role to access this route only dynamically

Comment: Just to make sure I now understand it correctly: you already have a role-matching access system like the one I mentioned in my answer, but you want to dynamically update the roles that can access a specific route. Is that right?

Comment: I have a role system in API when admin create a role will save into DB table and admin also create the menu (sidebar to visit the route) and assign it to a particular role who can access it so this role need to add on meta of a route which assigns by admin so later I can check it when a login user can have role to access it

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer

Comment: You're welcome! You can mark the answer as the correct answer for future reference to other SO users.